# what does "is chanced but not forced by" something, mean in the below context

Tags: expressions, complex-sentences

the below text is from : [Global Origins of the Modern Self, from Montaigne to Suzuki
By Avram Alpert](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=egyUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=%22our+mind+is+chanced,+but+not+forced,+by+language%22&source=bl&ots=IWaXnO0dyC&sig=ACfU3U3beOM9M1L3ZZiGoPlAnhZo_-jVEQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6__3n88TuAhVOQMAKHR4aBTEQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22our%20mind%20is%20chanced%2C%20but%20not%20forced%2C%20by%20language%22&f=false)

I have problem with the underline text:

> our mind is chanced, but not forced, by language.

what that means ? is this a correct understanding: our mind is formed accidentally by the language rather than forced to be formed by language.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you say who wrote this, and whether it is original English text, or a translation?

Comment: I have updated the question ... the text is original English ...

Comment: I wonder if it might be a typo? Perhaps "changed" instead of "chanced"?

Comment: @user888379 - The author repeats the phrase about 5 times in the book, so it's unlikely it's a simple typo.

Comment: @HotLicks Good to know - neither "chanced" nor "changed" made a lot of sense to me, but the latter seemed marginally more plausible.

Comment: Better to be chanced by language than mischanced by fashionable academicese.

Answer (score 3):

The sources (Montaigne, Alpert, Cavell) are authoritative and this question deserves reflection rather than closure or dismissal.  Let me construct a justifiable chain of reasoning for this use.

> Chance = to risk something
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/risk)

> Risk = : possibility of loss or injury
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/risk)

Although *risk* is usually used to refer to unwelcome possibilities, the key aspect here is that it refers to *possibility*. To chance something is to expose it to various possibilities. Not all these possibilities are necessarily bad. For example, when gambling, we may “chance our luck” on the throw of the dice.

Hence, if our minds are chanced by language, they are exposed to various possibilities (of meaning, connotation, ways of thought, ways of expression etc) by the language we use and the restrictive ways language influences our understanding and its developmemt (our epidemiological processes).

Comment: this is the best answer I got from this website ... thanks for the time you put to answer so nice and accurate the question.. thanks again

Comment: Kind of you. I hope you continue to use the site. It has many well-informed people who will enjoy helping you.